# The normality graph and p-value result are different

Tags: r, normalization, p-value

Hello This is my first question in this website.

I want to make the results about normality test.

If I make some normality test graph(Q-Q plot) and check the result is normality.
[image]

But, when I do shapiro.test with the same data with R program, It says It is not normality(p<0.05).

[image]

How can I match the results of graph and p-value?

Comment: Those data are not normal, they're over-dispersed.

Comment: Graph shows the same as shapiro test.